# Dart program exits without executing last statement

Tags: dart, stream

I'm trying to understand Streams and wrote some code. 
Everything seems to work, the program exits with status code 0. *But* it doesn't print the 'loop done' and 'main done' strings. I can't figure out why.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Stream<int> countStream(int to) async* {
      for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
              yield i;
      }
}

class Retry {
    StreamController<int> _outgoing;

    Retry(Stream<int> incoming) {
        _outgoing = StreamController<int>();
        _outgoing.addStream(incoming);
    }

    Future<void> process() async {
        await for (final i in _outgoing.stream) {
            print("got $i");
        }
        print('loop done'); // Not printed
    }
}

void main() async {
  var stream = countStream(4);
  var retry = Retry(stream);
  await retry.process();
  print('main done'); // Not printed
}
```

Comment: It doesn't explain but I noticed that removing the `async` in main (and the `await` in `retry.process()`) makes it work as expected. So it might be related to how async functions are implemented under the hood. In any case, this looks super weird to me.

Comment: It also works if you make `_outgoing` a `Stream<int>` instead of `StreamController`.

Comment: That might be because the stream is never closed, so it keeps awaiting for a value, try adding `Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () => _outgoing.close());` at the end of the `Retry` constructor and you'll see that in 10 seconds all the messages will be printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_outgoing.stream` is never closed, so code after the `await for` will never execute. The VM does notice that there also won't be any *new* events on that stream so nothing else will ever happen, and it can exit. You could fix the bug with:

```
_outgoing.addStream(incoming).whenComplete(() {
    _outgoing.close();
});
```

Comment: That sounds awful cleaver for a VM.

Comment: s/cleaver/clever (not very clever of me)

Comment: The VM is "clever" in that it has an event queue, and when that event queue is empty, and there are no open input ports or active timers left which can add anything to the event queue, then it just stops. Your code is written so that at some point, there is no more events in the queue. That happens when the `countStream` stream completes. There is code waiting for events, but no remaining code scheduled which can create those events. And then the VM closes down.