# In Dart, why waiting for a trivial ("empty") StreamController stream immediately exits program?

Tags: dart, async-await

This is the backbone of a simple program that uses a StreamController to listen on some input stream and outputs some other data on its own stream as a reaction:

```dart
import 'dart:async';     

main() async {     
    var c = StreamController(         
            onListen: (){},         
            onPause: (){},         
            onResume: (){},         
            onCancel: (){});         

    print("start");         
    await for (var data in c.stream) {         
            print("loop");         
    }         

    print("after loop");         
}
```

Output:

```
$ dart cont.dart
start
$ dart
```

Why does this code exit immediately at the await for line without executing neither print("loop") nor print("after loop") ?

Note: in the original program, onListen() will receive the input stream and subscribe to it. The loop actually works until calling subscription.cancel() on the input stream, when it also suddenly exits, without any chance to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised by this, but then again all of `async/await` code is converted to `.then()`s  and it seems everything can't be perfectly translated.

It seems this is part of the answer: You need to close the stream in another task to get out of the `await for`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169492/dart-program-exits-without-executing-last-statement) is a previous related question. Since we don't close it, lines after `await for` do not execute. Here's an example that avoids this:

```
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  var c = StreamController(
      onListen: () {},
      onPause: () {},
      onResume: () {},
      onCancel: () {});

  print("start");
  await Future.wait(<Future>[producer(c), consumer(c)]);

  print("after loop");
}

Future producer(StreamController c) async {
  // this makes it print "loop" as well
  // c.add("val!"); 
  await c.close();
}

Future consumer(StreamController c) async {
  await for (var data in c.stream) {
    print("loop");
  }
}
```

which prints:

```
start
after loop
```

So, moral of the story is,

1. Never leave a StreamController unattended or weird things will happen.
2. Some async functions that you wait on will break your code, even bypassing your try/finally block!

I thought I knew async/await inside out, but this second point scares me now.

Comment: Ok, but why ? Will my app suddenly exit in the user's face ? When ?

Comment: I don't think so. Note that it is not Flutter, yet, until you call `runApp()` with a widget. Since you're not awaiting on anything there it should be fine. I think `runApp()` has some kind of a `while(true)` as its event loop somewhere. I think this only means that an async function you called may terminate weirdly. The app would stay fine.

Comment: On a second thought, the only problem here is the main function returning and app exiting because of it. A function with some `.then()` calls in it returns just the same. The `.then()`s advance or not. In this case, they do not advance. So, in a Flutter scenario, it would be just like any other `async` function that does not ever complete.